# Perl File::Fetch Failed HTTP response: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: perl, fetch

I'm using a simple perl script to try and download a file from the following URL:
http://www.londonstockexchange.com/products-and-services/trading-services/setsqx/ccp-securities.xls

```
use File::Fetch;
my $url = 'http://www.londonstockexchange.com/products-and-services/trading-services/setsqx/ccp-securities.xls';
my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url);
my $file = $ff->fetch() or die $ff->error;
```

I am getting:

Fetch failed! HTTP response: 500 Internal Server Error [500 Can't connect to www.londonstockexchange.com:80 (connect: Connection refused)]

Could not open socket to 'www.londonstockexchange.com', 'Connection refused

Any ideas how i can get past this?

Comment: This works fine for me. I guess it will be something to do with your local environment, proxy settings etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could not open socket to 'www.londonstockexchange.com', 'Connection refused
>
> Any ideas how i can get past this?

Direct connection to this site is blocked somewhere.
If you are inside a company there is probably a firewall and some proxy you are required to use. Ask your system administrator.