# python requests http response 500 (site can be reached in browser)

Tags: python, python-2.7, request

I am trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here, but I keep getting lost...

In python 2.7, I'm running following code:

```
>>> import requests
>>> req = requests.request('GET', 'https://www.zomato.com/praha/caf%C3%A9-a-restaurant-z%C3%A1ti%C5%A1%C3%AD-kunratice-praha-4/daily-menu')
>>> req.content
'<html><body><h1>500 Server Error</h1>\nAn internal server error occured.\n</body></html>\n'
```

If I open this one in browser, it responds properly. I was digging around and found similar one with urllib library ([500 error with urllib.request.urlopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912257/500-error-with-urllib-request-urlopen)), however I am not able to adapt it, even more I would like to use requests here.

I might be hitting here some missing proxy setting, as suggested for example here ([Perl File::Fetch Failed HTTP response: 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317224/perl-filefetch-failed-http-response-500-internal-server-error)), but can someone explain me, what is the proper workaround with this one?

Comment: Have you tried requesting any other page? Maybe you need to add a User-Agent header from Firefox or something like that, because the page doesn't respond to queries by the python request library.

Comment: From looking at what happens in the network log when you load this page in a browser, it's at least in part a React app that dynamically renders its content in the browser. You are not likely to have much luck scraping it directly with `requests`.

Comment: @Maurice: yes, I had. I have problems just wish some of them, the rest is working...

Comment: @BillGribble : What would you please recommend as an universal approach to scraping web pages as general?

Comment: There's no universal answer.  `requests` is great for fetching stuff with HTTP(S) but if you need to see what's in a browser you need a browser.   I have had good luck with [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) when you simply have to scrape a page that's mostly rendered by Javascript.  It gives you an API that lets you drive and query a running browser. If you can find the underlying API endpoints that the page is pulling its data from you can use `requests` and you'll be better off.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One thing that is different with the browser request is the User-Agent; however you can alter it using requests like this:

```
url = 'https://www.zomato.com/praha/caf%C3%A9-a-restaurant-z%C3%A1ti%C5%A1%C3%AD-kunratice-praha-4/daily-menu'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.90 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code) #should be 200
```

## Edit

Some web applications will also check the `Origin` and/or the `Referer` headers (for example for AJAX requests); you can set these in a similar fashion to `User-Agent`.

```
headers = {
    'Origin': 'http://example.com',
    'Referer': 'http://example.com/some_page'
}
```

Remember, you are setting these headers to basically bypass checks so please be a good netizen and don't abuse people's resources.

Answer (score 2):

The User-Agent, and also other header elements, could be causing your problem.

When I came accross this error I watched a regular request made by a browser using Wireshark, and it turned out there were things other than just the User-Agent in the header which the server expected to be there.

After emulating the header sent by the browser in python requests, the server stopped throwing errors.

Answer (score 2):

## But Wait! There's More!

The above answers did help me on the path to resolution, but I had to find still more things to add to my headers so that certain sites would let me in using python requests. Learning how to use Wireshark (suggested above) was a good new skill for me, but I found an easier way.

If you go to your developer view (right-click then click **Inspect** in Chrome), then go to the **Network** tab, and then select one of the **Names** at left and then look under **Headers** for **Requests Headers** and expand, you'll get a complete list of what your system is sending to the server. I started adding elements that I thought were most likely needed one at a time and testing until my errors went away. Then I reduced that set to the smallest possible set that worked. In my case, with my headers having only **User-Agent** to deal with other code issues, I only needed to add the **Accept-Language** key to deal with a few other sites. See picture below as a guide to the text above.

I hope this process helps others to find ways to eliminate undesirable python requests return codes where possible.

[image: Screen Shot of my Developer/Inspect Window in Chrome]