# Python requests module post return status code 500 error

Tags: python, post, get, python-requests

I want to login my university portal with request module.

```
import requests
r = requests.post("https://sabis.sakarya.edu.tr/tr/Login", data={"userName":"1111","Password":"xxx"})
print(r.status_code)
```

but r.status_code return 500.
Where i make mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python requests http response 500 (site can be reached in browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442568/python-requests-http-response-500-site-can-be-reached-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

If `r.status_code` returns `500` status code than your snippet is allright. The problem is from **server** side. Because, `5XX` issues are considered as **server internal issues**

Comment: but i can login to the server with browser

Comment: I think https://sabis.sakarya.edu.tr/tr/Login renders **form**  it is not an API endpoint !

Answer (score 0):

you need a authentication token for this to work. maybe your university has a API documentation available where you can see how to get this token. and even how to correctly do a post request using their API.
[image]

Comment: I can take authentication token by making get request, then how can i use that token?

Comment: store it in a variable and then add the value of that variable to the body or the header of your post request like this:

Comment: like this:
`payload = "{\n\t\"userName\":\"1111\",\n\t\"Password\":\"xxx\",\n\t\"__RequestVerificationToken\":\"njKqvavQ6C1ETT8qcivqX23jIhKxv-lAz0JmauV1btWoNNQonNReGqNJLRepJk-8IwrRo6ZoSImv04CoAw4KS96ewok1\"\n}"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)`

Comment: or this:
`payload = "{\n\t\"userName\":\"1111\",\n\t\"Password\":\"xxx\",\n\t\n}"
headers = {
    '__requestverificationtoken': "njKqvavQ6C1ETT8qcivqX23jIhKxv-lAz0JmauV1btWoNNQonNReGqNJLRepJk-8IwrRo6ZoSImv04CoAw4KS96ewok1",
    'content-type': "application/json"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)`